# Change MIUI 3.1.18 side letters in contacts app

Tags: android, frameworks

I saw that you are a MIUI multi-lang dev.. 
I was a dev for MIUI myself but that was for version 2.3.. and now they have changed the framework and added a framework from teir own..
What I need is to change the contacts sidebar lang to Hebrew BUT maintain English UI of the system..
Here are the steps I'm taking in order to (try) do that:
1. install framework-res.apk + framework-miui-res.apk
apktool if framework-xxxx.apk

1. decompile framework-res.apk + framework-miui-res.apk
   apktool d framework-xxxx.apk
2. in framework-res (in folder values-en-rUS) I'm changing: (File copyied from "values" folder)
   Original:
3. in framework-miui-res (in folder values-en-rUS) I'm changing: (File copyied from "values" folder)

translating the array Alphabet into Hebrew...

1. after that, I recompile framework-xxx folders (No errors here, only warnings about string(s) doesn't have default translation in bla bla bla"
2. delete "resources" folder and "resourses.arsc" file from original APKs.
3. copy above folder & file from framework-xxx/build/apk/ builded folder.
4. sign the APKs with zip tool.
5. mount system and copy the files..
6. Nothing work and everything crashes... :/

What am I doing wrong here? I have Galaxy Nexus with MIUI 3.1.18 (Latest!).

Please I need your help on that one..

Here is my log cat (pushed only the framework-res.. pushing framework-
Thanks,
Nir.

Answer (score 0):

Your doing the localization wrong. If your translation is Hewbrew, you need to make folders in framework-res and framework-miui-res like values-iw-rIL

Then copy the strings.xml from /values into those folders (for that apk). Don't ever touch /values.

Only the framework files require (iw-rIL), the rest of them will just require values-iw. Though this method does make an entire new Language called Hewbrew. However, the base /values should be in English so you will have English + in Hewbrew of whatever you translated.

Only replace resources.arsc, unless you are changing images. You only need to re-inject /res folder if you are changing images.

Comment: WOW! thanks for your answer!
I don't want to make my entire system in Hebrew.. I want it to stay in English... that's y I changed the strings into Hebrew, I will try it! Thanks!

Comment: I did what you said and the phone is stucked on Bootloop...In the XML file I only put the correct file with the translated Array / 2 Strings... and it stuck.... what is the problem? Why I can't do this, It's so simple! Damn!